# Is a "Anti" heat engine possible?

Tags: thermodynamics

The "Anti" heat engine is a misnomer what I mean is can you get mechanical work by removing heat from say atmospheric air via liquid nitrogen injection instead of adding heat via combustion or similar

Answer (score 4):

You can extract work from a temperature difference.  The greater the difference, the more efficiently work can be extracted.  So yes, you can create an engine that performs work when given a cold source.

The difficulty with cold is that there's a limit to how cold you can get.  You might get 200C or so difference between ambient and a really cold source, but you can get 1000C difference with a nice hot flame.  So the energy and power are much more easily extracted with the larger gradient.

The main problem is that it's easy to make a hot source by allowing introduced energy to be released.  We almost always create the high temperature pool at the point of use.

We can't make a big pool of liquid nitrogen with a simple chemical reaction, so cold sources are usually produced elsewhere with a energy-intensive heat extraction systems and then transported.  Given that, it's usually easier to redirect the energy that created the cold source in the first place than it is to use the liquid nitrogen as a "battery".

Comment: Would it be possible to get an increase in temperature by compressing air and then removing heat to get work or does that violate some law ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what specific process you're describing.  Most likely you can do that, but it requires an energy input, and there are losses in the process.  So most of the time it's easier to use whatever the energy input was in the first place.